# My VBA code overwrites my last row. How can I write the code to put new information on the next empty row?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, data-transfer

I followed a YouTube tutorial to copy data from one sheet into another sheet in the same workbook. Mind you, I have no experience in VBA.

I noticed that when I add a new entry it overwrites the previous row. I want the code to find the last empty row and add the newest entry there. So, if rows 1 and 2 have information, then the newest information gets transferred to row 3 and so forth.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Create and set variables for the Time Tracker & Master Data worksheets
Dim TTrk As Worksheet, MDat As Worksheet

Set TTrk = Sheet1
Set MDat = Sheet2

'Create and set variables for each cell in the Time Tracker sheet
Dim Name As Range, AddDate As Range, TotalHours As Range, Activity As Range, Client As Range, Category     As Range, AddHours As Range, TimeSpent As Range, Additional As Range

Set Name = TTrk.Range("C2")
Set AddDate = TTrk.Range("C3")
Set TotalHours = TTrk.Range("C5")
Set Activity = TTrk.Range("B8:B15")
Set Client = TTrk.Range("C8:C15")
Set Category = TTrk.Range("D8:D15")
Set AddHours = TTrk.Range("E8:E15")
Set TimeSpent = TTrk.Range("F8:F15")
Set Additional = TTrk.Range("G8:G15")

'Create a variable for the paste cell in the Master Data worksheet
Dim DestCell As Range

If MDat.Range("A2") = "" Then 'If A2 is empty
Set DestCell = MDat.Range("A2") '...then destination cell is A2
Else
Set DestCell = MDat.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) '...otherwise the next empty row

If MDat.Range("A2") = "" Then 'If A2 is empty
Set DestCell = MDat.Range("A2") '...then destination cell is A2
Else
Set DestCell = MDat.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) '...otherwise the next empty row

End If

'Copy and paste data from the Time Tracker worksheet to the Master Data worksheet
Name.Copy DestCell
AddDate.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 1)
TotalHours.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 2)
Activity.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 3)
Client.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 4)
Category.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 5)
AddHours.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 6)
TimeSpent.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 7)
Additional.Copy DestCell.Offset(0, 8)

'Clear the contents in the Time Tracker worksheet
AddDate.ClearContents
TotalHours.ClearContents
Activity.ClearContents
Client.ClearContents
Category.ClearContents
AddHours.ClearContents
TimeSpent.ClearContents
Additional.ClearContents

End Sub
```

I tried taking away certain coding and trying to find coding to add into my current code to see if it would resolve the issue, but I have no experience in VBA.

Comment: `Set DestCell = MDat.Range("A" & mdat.cells(mdat.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row +1)`

Comment: Hi again, so in my Master Data sheet, if the "Name" and "Date" (Columns A and B) are blank, then if I type information on the Time Tracker sheet and submit it, then data still overwrites the information because there are blanks on columns A and B. I think these columns need to have the name and date to be copied down every time. Can I fix this in my original code? Thanks!

Comment: Count the rows in a column that won't be blank

Comment: The solution here is to learn python. That'll be significantly easier

Answer (score 2):

### Copy Ranges Side-By-Side

**A Quick Fix**

- Reference the destination cell in the following way:

```vb
Dim DestCell As Range: Set DestCell = MDat.Range("A2")

With MDat.UsedRange
    Dim drOffset As Long:
    drOffset = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row - DestCell.Row + 1
    If drOffset > 0 Then
        Set DestCell = DestCell.Offset(drOffset)
    End If
End With
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**A Simplification**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Const SRC_RANGES As String = "C2,C3,C5,B8:G15"
    Dim sClearFlags(): sClearFlags = VBA.Array(0, 1, 1, 1)
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet1
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet2
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        Dim drOffset As Long: drOffset = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row - dfCell.Row + 1
        If drOffset > 0 Then
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(drOffset)
        End If
    End With
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_RANGES)
        Dim arg As Range, n As Long
        For Each arg In .Areas
            ' Copy.
            arg.Copy dfCell
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(, arg.Columns.Count)
            ' Clear.
            If sClearFlags(n) = 1 Then
                arg.ClearContents
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Next arg
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Even taking in account what I was going to comment on, that the way he had it, would overwrite his ticker data if he just bases the last row of the A-column. Nice one!

Comment: Hi VBasic 2008, thank you for your response! I tried this and it shifted my data by 1 column. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @Notus_Panda Thanks. Interesting: For the big range I used the spilling formula `=WRAPROWS(SEQUENCE(48,,4),6)`. The Find method was failing (when copying once more) with `xlFormulas` but was working with `xlValues` which I don't like because it fails with hidden rows. Therefore I switched to a used range solution. Spilling formulas are quite a game changer.