# Cell formulas should not be copied

Tags: excel, vba

Can you help me with the formula? It works fine, but I need it to only copy cell values and formats, not formulas. I've tried everything and can't get it to work right.

```
Private Sub Copy_Paste() 'Kopiraj in prilepi podatke v spodnji del sheeta
    
    Const SRC_RANGES As String = "A4:AA9"
    Dim sClearFlags(): sClearFlags = VBA.Array(0, 1, 1, 1)
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A4"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet2
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet2
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        Dim drOffset As Long: drOffset = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row - dfCell.Row + 1
        If drOffset > 0 Then
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(drOffset)
        End If
    End With
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_RANGES)
        Dim arg As Range, n As Long
        For Each arg In .Areas
            ' Copy.
            arg.Copy dfCell
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(, arg.Columns.Count)
            ' Clear.
            If sClearFlags(n) = 1 Then
                arg.ClearContents
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Next arg
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Delete `Destination:=dfCell`

Comment: @Blackcat Thank you for help. But i posted the wrong formula. I have corrected the error.

Comment: Instead of using Copy/Paste just assign the values e.g. `TargetRange.Value = arg.Value` - you will need to work out what the target range address is rather than just the first cell

Comment: Only `arg.Copy: dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Below

**A Quick Fix**

- Replace the 2nd (bottom) *With* statement with this:

```vb
Dim arg As Range, n As Long

For Each arg In sws.Range(SRC_RANGES).Areas
    arg.Copy
    dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    dfCell.Resize(arg.Rows.Count, arg.Columns.Count).Value = arg.Value
    Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(, arg.Columns.Count)
Next arg

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

**A Simplification**

- If you don't need the full extent of the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626257)'s functionality i.e. if you just want to copy the range below, adjacent to the bottom-most row, you can simplify with this:

```vb
Sub CopyBelow() 'Kopiraj in prilepi podatke v spodnji del sheeta
    
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "A4:AA9"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet2
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    With rg.Offset(rg.Rows.Count)
        rg.Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Value = rg.Value
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works! Thank you.